# How to verify if two systems are in sync

Tags: python, database-design, automation, architecture, system

I have a requirement to test two applications (via automation using Python).

The requirement is for example we have a system called “www.abc.com”
where we develop and merge code in every 2 weeks and then we create a another system called “www.xyz.com” ( basically it is backup to the first system ), everytime we do a release and add/edit in the main system, we update in our back up system.

Now the question is i need to tests both the system, after every release (every 2 weeks) to see if they both are in sync (identical).

how do i fire a python automation test script (multiple tests) to check if for example databases, servers, UI, front end, check if code base are same in both systems? can i do that if yes any  help and advice , please suggest so that i can implement possible solutions .

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you could approach this:

Assuming you are using some sort of source control you could write a script to make sure that the repo is up to date and then report back the results. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938723/git-how-to-check-if-a-local-repo-is-up-to-date) [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418092/how-can-i-set-up-git-branch-for-automatic-backups/25418215). This probably won't cover the data in your databases, but there are numerous ways to back database backups and it will depend what programs you are using.

Another or additional way you might check is to write a script to gather a list of hashes or checksums of all the files you care about in both systems and then compare the list for differences.